# How to render svg with cripEdges under IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm trying to render svg lines. I can set `shape-rendering` to `crispEdges` under chrome, but it doesn't work with IE11. How can I do the same with IE11? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Try [-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges) instead. Probably won't work in Edge, however. A better solution would be to fix your SVG so that the lines are matched to the pixel grid (with half-pixel X and Y offsets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to set the attribute of the svg element, not the "style" of it. I was setting it to 
`<line style="shape-rendering: crispEdges" />`. It should be `<line shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>`